# How to reduce size of testcomplete test report?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, report, desktop-application, testcomplete

I am using testcomplete to automate desktop based application. While running the automation pack, the generated test report size is huge because all operations are being saved as screenshot. I am unable to attach this report as evidence. So is there any way to reduce the test report ? Or Any way to select specific screenshot to be a part of report ? Or any way to reduce pixel of images inorder to reduce size ?
Thanks In Advance.
(Tried compressing, but didn't change size much)

Answer (score 0):

You set up GeneralEvents (edit the Advanced>Events->GeneralEvents):

- https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/advanced/handling-events/about.html
  Here you see a list Events To handle like what to do on Log.Warning. Add your own script.

Below is my Script That logs a screenshot everytime I issue a Log.Warning() in my testcode:

```
// Executed each time test logs warning
function GeneralEvents_OnLogWarning(Sender, LogParams){
    if(Project.Variables.ErrorsDuringTestCaseExecution) {
        Project.Variables.ErrorsDuringTestCaseExecution.push(LogParams.MessageText);
    }
    Log.Picture(Sys.Desktop, "Warning screenshot");
}
```

For explicit do a picture you can add a function and call it directly in your code:

- https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/program-objects/picture/index.html